# How to reconfigure libtool after upgrading gcc

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, gcc

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and was hit by [this gcc bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.6/+bug/968766). In order to fix this I installed a more recent version of gcc (following [this procedure](http://www.swiftsoftwaregroup.com/upgrade-gcc-4-7-ubuntu-12-04/)). Now `gcc -v` and `g++ -v` both work, but packages that use libtool still use gcc-4.6.3.

How can I reconfigure libtool to pick up the updated gcc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: The problem didn't really have anything to do with libtool (although it was revealed when building packages that used libtool). I had updated gcc and g++ to 4.8, but cpp was still at 4.6.3. After installing cpp-4.8 the problem is fixed.

Just for the record, the following should work fine for upgrading gcc to 4.8 on ubuntu 12.04:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8 cpp-4.8
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp /usr/bin/cpp-4.8 100 \
    --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 \
    --slave /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8
```